# passing variable on react handler typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, type-assertion

I wanted to pass a variable (SearchBoolean) to be logged everytime a button handler function is invoked. So I did this:

```
type SearchFormProps = {
    styles: React.CSSProperties;
    classNames: string;
};

const onSubmitHandler=(event: React.SyntheticEvent, isSearched?:boolean)=>{
  event.preventDefault();
   const target = event.target as typeof event.target & {
      username: { value: string };
    };
  const username = target.username.value; 
  console.log(username, isSearched);
}

export const SearchForm=({classNames, styles}: SearchFormProps)=>{
  const SearchBoolean = useContext(SearchBooleanContext);
  const {isSearched, setIsSearched} = SearchBoolean;
  // console.log('SearchBooleans', isSearched);
  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={()=>onSubmitHandler(event, isSearched)}>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicUsername">
        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter username" name="username" />
      </Form.Group>
      <Button variant="primary" type="submit" >
        Search
      </Button>
      </Form>
    </div>
   
  );
}
```

but this only gave me error that the event is deprecated and not assignable. If I removed the event from the callback, it still persists to require me passing two arguments. I assigned "?" optional on argument event, but it just made it worst. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The error you're experiencing is because you're passing the event object incorrectly to the onSubmit handler. In your code, you're not explicitly passing the event object to the onSubmitHandler function.

```
 <Form onSubmit={(event)=>onSubmitHandler(event, isSearched)}>
```